# Where condition within Window Function

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions, partition-by

I didn't find any relative information if it was possible to use like a "where" or condition within a window function.

Considering the following table :

| date_dt | city | rain | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/01/01 | London | 10 | 3 |
| 2022/01/01 | Berlin | 22 | 4 |
| 2022/01/01 | Paris | 22 | 5 |
| 2022/01/02 | Berlin | 5 | 3 |
| 2022/01/02 | Chicago | 9 | 10 |
| 2022/01/10 | London | 10 | 4 |
| 2022/01/31 | London | 20 | 5 |
| 2022/01/31 | Paris | 2 | 3 |
| 2022/02/01 | Paris | 10 | 5 |

I would like to perfom specific calcul on the european cities and other aggregation on all the cities. Table is in reality way more complex (2M row and 10+ columns), so the query should be efficient.

For all the cities, I'm checking the average temperature. For European cities (London, Berlin, Paris), the sum(Rain) for a given month, should not be exceed 100. I used a window function to perform this operation. The only problem is that it's taking into account Chicago city as well in the computation.

Is there anyway to apply a "where" in the case statement or within the window function to not take into account Chicago ?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
 date_dt,
 cities,
 avg(temperature),
 CASE
   WHEN sum(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_dt)  ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ) = 100
    then 0
   WHEN sum(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_dt) ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) < 100
    then rain
   WHEN sum(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_dt)  ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and current row) > 100 and (100 - sum(rain) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_dt) ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)) > 0
   then 100 - sum(Stakes) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_dt),EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_dt) ROWS BETWEEN unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
   else 0
 end as rain_corrected_europe
FROM staging.weather
```

Comment: `sum(case city when "chicago" then null else rain end) over(...)`

Comment: @astentx thanks, I tried your solution which working well. But because I have to use the windows functions multiple times, it's taking lot of time to execute. Any idea about to shorten the querying time?

Comment: can you calculate using a subquery and then use case when outside?